# DB2 Connect licensing problem (SQLSTATE=42968)

Tags: zos, db2-zos

I require DB2 Connect installed on my laptop to allow an application to read a DB2 database on a z/OS box. Due to issues with slow VPN I was unable to download a licensed copy of it from my firms server, so I downloaded a trial version (v9.7) from IBM Website. I am now in position where I can copy the licensed copy over the company network and install that (v 11.1).

I have uninstalled v9.7 and installed v11.1 but when attempting to reference the DB I get the error:

> Logon Failure:42968: -1598: [IBM][CLI Driver]SQL1598N An attempt to
> connect to the datasbase server failed because of a licensing problem.
> SQLSTATE=42968.

I suspect that  the registry is ‘polluted’ with v9.7 stuff including the licence expired flag.

Is there something I can remove from the Registry that will resolve this and allow v11.1 to work ?